# Grapefruit for weight loss?

Tags: nutrition, fruit

There seem to be many people that claim grapefruit, in one form or another, helps dieters with weight loss.

**Is there any good academically-rigorous evidence to support any of these claims?**

Some of the claims:

> People who ate half of a grapefruit before each meal (without making any other dietary changes) shed an average of three and a half pounds over 12 weeks, found a study from the Nutrition and Metabolic Research Center at Scripps Clinic in La Jolla, California."

Source: http://www.health.com/health/gallery/0,,20564855_4,00.html

> The fruit's compounds aid in fat burning and stabilizing blood-sugar and insulin levels,' says Christine Gerbstadt, MD, author of Doctor's Detox Diet.

Source: http://www.health.com/health/gallery/0,,20564855_4,00.html

Further evidence of notability is the 'Grapefruit Diet', which [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grapefruit_diet) describes as a *fad diet*.

Comment: This would appear to be the referenced study: http://online.liebertpub.com/doi/abs/10.1089/jmf.2006.9.49?journalCode=jmf

Comment: According to this abstract, similar weight loss resulted from either water or grapefruit juice prior to meals which leads to a conclusion that "a low energy dense dietary preload in a caloric restricted diet is a highly effective weight loss strategy." However, those who drank grapefruit juice also "experienced significantly greater benefits in lipid profiles". ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3039556

Comment: Maybe I'm not familiar with the protocol here - but what is the question being asked, exactly?

Comment: Mark, There seems to be many people (as evidenced by my references) that claim grapefruit,in one form or another, helps dieters with weight loss. Is there any good academically-rigorous evidence to support any of these claims?

Comment: @John R: I added it to the main question body to make it more clear.

Comment: Related: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/803/does-celery-help-you-lose-weight

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/5122/is-it-true-that-eating-some-foods-burns-calories

Comment: @Sklivvz Question 5122 comes down to "Do any foods actually contain less calories than it takes to chew and digest them". Not the same.

Comment: @JohnR I think that should be decided by the community. I am not taking a strong position here :-)